# How to run PowerMock v1.74 with java.net.InetAddress static method

Tags: java, powermockito

I have been reading a lot about PowerMockito to mock static methods.  So I have been trying to use v1 (not v2), although I don't really care which version of PowerMockito or testNG I use.  I figure I missed some critical detail here in the configuration, but I am at a loss.

Using Oracle Java 1.8

subprojects.gradle:

```
testCompile group: 'org.testng',                  name: 'testng',               version: '6.14.3'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock',           name: 'powermock-module-testng',  version: '1.7.4'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock',           name: 'powermock-api-mockito',    version: '1.7.4'
```

I checked my versioning of modules [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-Maven#TestNG)

Test class

```
import org.mockito.*;
import org.mockito.invocation.*;
import org.mockito.stubbing.*;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.*;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.*;
import org.testng.*;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;

@PrepareForTest({java.net.InetAddress.class})
public class testClass extends PowerMockTestCase {
  @Test   
  public void exampleTest()
     throws IOException, URISyntaxException, MyCustomException {

    mockStatic(InetAddress.class);
    // I use these three functions, so I think I have to mock them all?
    when(InetAddress.getByName(Mockito.anyString()))
        .thenReturn(InetAddresses.forString("111.0.0.111"));    
    when(InetAddress.getByAddress(Mockito.anyObject()))
      .thenCallRealMethod();
    when(InetAddress.getLocalHost()).thenCallRealMethod();

    MyNewClass mnc = new MyNewClass();
    mnc.someCodeUsingInetAddress();
  }
```

This compiles and runs, but does not change the behavior of the function InetAddress.getByName() when called from someCodeUsingInetAddress().

Now I read [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System) that I need to label the class with 
`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`.  But IntelliJ won't let me import the PowerMockRunner.class from any of the possible sources, of which it is aware. Which also makes me wonder which one I should be trying to use.

```
org.testng.PowerMockRunner
org.testng.annotations.PowerMockRunner
org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockRunner
```

the list goes on...